# What would be the automaton YA file corresponding to this C program?

Tags: frama-c

In the context of verifying this program using Aorai plugin for frama-c, what would be the corresponding automaton in .ya file format ?

```
void f() {
    ;
}

void g(){
    ;
}

int main(){
    f();
    g();
    return 0;
}
```

My guess is this

```
%init: S0;
%accept: S4;

S0 : { CALL(main) } -> S1
   ;
S1 : { CALL(f) } -> S2
   ;
S2 : { CALL(g) } -> S3
   ;
S3 : {RETURN(main) } -> S4
   ;
S4 : -> S4
   ;
```

But I get this error using Aorai plugin

```
[aorai] Warning: Call to main does not follow automaton's specification. This path is assumed to be dead
[aorai] Threestateaut.c:12: Warning: 
  Call to main not conforming to automaton (pre-cond). Assuming it is on a dead path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that at **each** event a transition must be taken from the current state of the automaton. Here, when you are in `S2` after the `CALL` to `f`, the next event that happens is the `RETURN` from `f` to `main`, but the only transition from `S2` is guarded by `CALL(g)` (the beginning of the automaton describes thus a program where `f` itself calls `g`).

To fix this, you can either take the `RETURN` into account, as in

```
...
S2: { RETURN(f) } -> S3;
S3: { CALL(g)   } -> S4;
...
```

or use YA extensions (as described in [section 3.1.3 of the manual](https://www.frama-c.com/download/frama-c-aorai-manual.pdf), which in particular allow indicating that you have a `CALL(f)` directly followed by a `RETURN(f)` with:

```
...
S2: { f() } -> S3;
...
```

Actually, with these extensions, the complete execution flow can be specified in a more compact way, since you can nest call sequences:

```
%init: S0;
%accept: S1;

S0 : { main([f();g()]) } -> S1;

S1: -> S1;
```